# JsApi sometimes gets broken

Tags: javascript, npapi, firebreath

We're using the JsApin for two way communication between the plugin and the page js.
Sometimes this object just stops working.

Here's what we're doing:

```
<object type="...">
    ...
    <param name="onload" value="pluginloaded" />
    ...
</object>

var myObj = {
    element: ..., // reference to the dom element for the object tag
    ...
}

function pluginloaded(jsapi) {
    myObj.jsapi = jsapi;
}
```

As you can see we keep a reference to both the DOM object element and the JsApi object that is being passed to the onload method.
When there's a try to execute a method on the plugin (or a property) it will first try  `myObj.jsapi.method()` and if that failed then 'myObj.element.method()`, and if that fails then that will be reported.

Statistics show that it doesn't happen very frequently, but it does indeed happen, though I have no idea how to reproduce it, just sometimes happens.

Any idea what might cause this object to be unavailable? from the js perspective the jsapi object is undefined, and the object element just doesn't have the method/properties which are exposed from the plugin.

Thanks.

Comment: does it matter if you use the saved jsapi from the pluginloaded function call or access the methods on the html element itself?

Comment: No, that doesn't matter, the problem is that neither one works (when this issue happens), the jsapi object is undefined and on the element itself the added methods/properties are undefined. any idea why?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Without spending more time looking at your actual project it's hard to say for sure, but this sounds to me like you're actually unloading and/or reloading your plugin.  The most common thing that causes this is when you move it around in the DOM -- for example, if you use javascript to create the object tag, and you set the .type before you put it in the DOM:

```
var obj = Document.create("object");
obj.type = "application/x-mytype";

someElement.appendChild(obj);
```

This seems like a good idea, but the browser actually will partially destroy the plugin object when you do this.  Similarly, if you set css `display: none` or `overflow: {anything here}` on the plugin object or any of its parents it can cause this.

Anyway, however it is happening I bet you are unloading the plugin, thus invalidating the jsapi object you grabbed.

Comment: ok, that's very interesting and good to know. I will look into this and see what is we're doing that looks like what you described, but is there a way to catch this problem at runtime and somehow fix it? the js part notices it but can't notify the plugin. is there a way for the plugin to know? and if so, can i then call a js method and "reset" it with the new jsapi instance? thanks.

Comment: From my last day experiments the only way I managed to reproduce the problem was by toggling between display values. The thing is that once I change it back to block then the plugin calls the onload method which sends the new jsapi, which in our case should fix the problem..  In any case I think I managed to come up with a solution by having a two directional "pulse" between the js and the plugin, if after X time the plugin does not get a call from the js it assumes that the api is broken and sends a new one. I shared the repo: https://github.com/rounds/FireBreathBrokenJsApi

Comment: I prefer the fix that involves not having the HTML do things that break the plugin, but whatever works for you =]

Comment: yeah,but that's easier said than done.. especially since i have no idea what exactly causes it. so in the meanwhile I'd prefer that the plugin/js can watch for such errors and fix them at runtime.